# Enviar Post Ajax fora do mesmo Projeto

Tags: php, jquery, ajax

Explicando melhor, no Eclipse PHP eu tenho Projeto 1 e Projeto 2, sendo que estou emulando o PHP no Xampp, eu queria enviar um Post via Ajax do Projeto 1 ao Projeto 2, mas não estou conseguindo.

Erro:

```
XMLHttpRequest cannot load http://localhost/appread/Post.php. 
Response for preflight is invalid (redirect)
```

Código Ajax:

```
 $('#btn-sinc').click(function(){

    $.ajax({
          type: "POST",
          url: 'http://localhost/appread/Post.php',
          data: "cliente="+ClienteStorage,
          contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",
          dataType: 'json',
          success: function (data){
              alert('Dado Enviado');
          }

    });

});
```

Tenho quase certeza que o código não está muito certo.
Se alguém puder dar uma mão agradeço.

Comment: dá uma lida: https://d-mueller.de/blog/cross-domain-ajax-guide/

Comment: Muito obrigado @VirgilioNovic